# How to lock/unlock layers in pdf using pdfbox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I see there is functionality to enable/disable layers with pdfbox. Below is the sample code for that.

```
        Document document = PDDocument.load(new File(
                        "layers.pdf"));
        PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDOptionalContentProperties ocprops = catalog.getOCProperties();
        PDOptionalContentGroup group = ocprops.getGroup(layerName);
        boolean isVisible = ocprops.isGroupEnabled(layerName);
```

But is there a way to lock/unlock layers using pdfbox?

Comment: PDFBox does not (yet) have custom methods to lock or unlock groups. But it should be easy to follow the pattern of the `PDOptionalContentProperties` code and the PDF specification and create such methods yourself.